# Оптимизация петель методом Даффа, кто-нибудь применял его на практике?

Tags: c, оптимизация

Оригинальный copypaste. Функция копирования по указателю.

```
register short *to, *from;
    register count;
    {
        register n=(count+7)/8;
        switch(count%8){
        case 0: do{ *to = *from++;
        case 7:     *to = *from++;
        case 6:     *to = *from++;
        case 5:     *to = *from++;
        case 4:     *to = *from++;
        case 3:     *to = *from++;
        case 2:     *to = *from++;
        case 1:     *to = *from++;
            }while(--n>0);
        }
    }
```

Выгода очевидна. Петля распараллеливается, следовательно уменьшается количество сравнений с условием цикла и благодаря switch без break первый проход можно начать из любой точки, что позволяет без проблем копировать количество байт не кратное количеству строк внутри петли, при этом оставив ее параллельной.

Кто-нибудь замерял насколько код выше работает быстрее обычной петли снизу?

```
do {                        
    *to = *from++;        
} while(--count > 0);
```

Comment: Классный код. Всё копировать в два байта? (Можно скопировать только последний short -- результат будет тем же.

Comment: Может все таки to++?

Comment: В оригинале автор с помощью \*to указывал на порт ввода/вывода поэтому нету ++. Если нужно скопировать в память то надо заменить \*to на \*to++

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых "быстро" и "вывод в порт" - это не совместимые понятия. На вывод в порт потратится сколько тактов, что разница от разворачивания цикла будет не заметна.

Во-вторых, если рассматривать копирование вообще, то быстрее будет копировать не 8 раз по байту, а 1 раз по uint64_t, или самый широкий тип, который пролазит в шину памяти.

И наконец, при использовании устройства Даффа, каждая итерация цикла будет начинаться на не выровненных данных, что может несколько уменьшить производительность копирования.